# Foreground overlapping in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two constraintlayouts nested in another constraintlayout. I've set a foreground image for the parent constraintlayout but the image overlaps on the other two layouts as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYU8.png)

I've searched online but I can't find how to solve this problem

This is my xml file so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
    android:foreground="@drawable/deviworkslogo_only_gears_white"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:foregroundTint="#E6E6E6"
    android:foregroundTintMode="src_in">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#D31212"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/libraryBtn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/libraryBtn"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/libraryBtn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#3973AF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want to obtain is that the foreground image remains behind the nested constraintlayouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to remain behind the nested `ConstraintLayout`s you probably want to use the `android:background` attribute instead of `android:foreground`.

In the code you provided, in the parent `ConstraintLayout`, you have the following line:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/deviworkslogo_only_gears_white"
```

You need to switch to use **background** instead of **foreground** if what you want is for the image to be behind the nested `ConstraintLayout`s.

From the quick description of `android:foreground` attribute we can read the following:
"*Defines the drawable to draw over the content. This can be used as an overlay. The foreground drawable participates in the padding of the content if the gravity is set to fill.*"